# Can GTM be used in java (jar) stand alone application? (no mobile/android)

Tags: java, analytics, google-tag-manager, google-api-java-client

More info:
It runs on Windows and is builded with javafx

If the answer is "no" do you know any other tool/way we could use to get metrics?

Comment: GTM by itself does not collect any metrics at all. You could go for Google Analytics and the measurement protocol  (if your app has internet connectivity and can send http requests).

Comment: I know GTM does not collect the metrics but allows me to TAG elements without needing help from the developers in order to collect the data via GA, so, my question remains... Can GTM be used in this app? (Yes, the app has internet connectivity)